# Excel: Search within column and then search within the respective row

Tags: excel, search, find, worksheet-function

I have a table, let's call it `Table 1`, with a column `identifier`, `ID`, and for each `ID` (i.e. row) there are various respective dates.

In another sheet, there is a monthly calendar but also with a column having the ID.

 
I would like to have a function that would first read through the first column to determine which is the proper row from `Table 1`. After doing this it would check whether in this month there is any corresponding date from `Table 1` for this particular `ID` (i.e. row). 

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Might be worth adding VBA tag to your query as I think you are looking for an answer in a UDF

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the `index,match,match` way.

If you haven't used it yet,I will shortly explain.

The `index` function works as follows:

```
=index(A1:E10, 2, 5)
'Returns the value in the second row and the fifth column of the range "A1:E10" so the value of "E2"
```

The `match` function works as follows:

```
=match("Hello",A1:E1, 0)
'returns the index at which it found the value "Hello" e.g C1 has the value "Hello" it will return 3. The third paramter "0" says you want an EXACT match
```

Lets say your table is in range `A1:D10` first row is header and first column IDS.

```
ID    |    Value1    |    Value2    |    Value 3 
1     |     ....
2     |     ....
..
```

Now you want to find the entry at `"Value1" with ID = 3`

```
=index(A1:D10, match("Value1",B1:D1, 0), match(3, A1:A10, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks ! This is quite helpful. If I understand you correctly, this would search for the proper column and then for the row. Is there any way to reverse that? Determine the proper row first and then determine the column.